# ansible is trowing a Syntax Error while loading YAML. did not find expected key

Tags: ansible

my yml looks like:

```yaml
---
# YAML documents begin with the document separator ---

# The minus in YAML this indicates a list item.  The playbook contains a list 
# of plays, with each play being a dictionary
-
 
  # Hosts: where our play will run and options it will run with
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  # Vars: variables that will apply to the play, on all target systems
  vars:
      DDVE_public_IP : 34.107.103.175
      destination_port: 3009
      Instance_id : 8529834022607504819
      S3_bucket_name : bucket_for_ddve_6

  # Tasks: the list of tasks that will be executed within the playbook
  tasks:
     - name: login access token
       uri:
          url: https://{{ DDVE_public_IP }}:{{ destination_port }}/{{ resource_path }}
          method: POST
          headers:
              Content-Type: application/json
          body_format: json
          body:
              username: sysadmin
              password: {{ Instance_id }}
        return_content: yes
        ignore_errors: yes
        register: rest_post
        vars:
            resource_path: rest/v1.0/auth

      - name: DEBUG / GOT INFO
        debug:
            msg: "{{ rest_post.json }}"
        when: rest_post.status ==  201

  # Handlers: the list of handlers that are executed as a notify key from a task

  # Roles: list of roles to be imported into the play

# Three dots indicate the end of a YAML document
...

ansible-playbook ddve6-post-deploy-object-store.yml
```

> [WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available.
> [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that
> the implicit localhost does not match 'all'.
> ERROR! We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each:
> JSON: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
>
> Syntax Error while loading YAML.
> did not find expected key
>
> The error appears to be in '/Users/juergen/Documents/DPSCodeAcademy/Ansible/#dev/ddve/ddve6-post-deploy-object-store.yml': line 30, column 9, but may
> be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
>
> The offending line appears to be:
>
> ```
>              password: {{ Instance_id }}
>        return_content: yes
>        ^ here
> ```

I have no idea where that error is coming as I can't find the responding problem here.

Answer (score 1):

You just have some indentation errors in that YAML document. Pick an indentation level (e.g., 2 spaces for every level) and stick with it consistently. Many editors have plugins that will syntax check your YAML documents while you write them.

The following validates correctly:

```yaml
---

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    DDVE_public_IP: 34.107.103.175
    destination_port: 3009
    Instance_id: 8529834022607504819
    S3_bucket_name: bucket_for_ddve_6

  tasks:
    - name: login access token
      uri:
        url: https://{{ DDVE_public_IP }}:{{ destination_port }}/{{ resource_path }}
        method: POST
        headers:
          Content-Type: application/json
        body_format: json
        body:
          username: sysadmin
          password: "{{ Instance_id }}"
      return_content: true
      ignore_errors: true
      register: rest_post
      vars:
        resource_path: rest/v1.0/auth

    - name: DEBUG / GOT INFO
      debug:
        msg: "{{ rest_post.json }}"
      when: rest_post.status ==  201
```

Note that it is highly uncommon to terminate your YAML documents with the `...` marker.

Comment: Thanks for that. Now I run into some ReST uri issues